# Content's width

Tags: html, css

How to make the div to only take the content's width?

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 63px;
  z-index: 20;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: gold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='modal'>
lorem ipsum<br>and<br>lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 63px;
  z-index: 20;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class='modal'>
  lorem ipsum<br>and<br>lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, anytime :)

Comment: @VXp, why is so important to keep a `space` between `top:` and `63px` ?

Comment: He added a colon, not a space. It was a typo from my end.

Comment: It was a typo from his end, he forgot it in the first place, and spaces are just for readability, and it also looks nicer.

Comment: @Vxp your new title is not suitable for the essence of question. It's not just about `content's width` but about `width:auto` + `position fixed; margin:auto;`

Comment: 1. width: auto is by default 2. position: fixed or any other styling doesn't matter 3. It's clear what the desired result should be 4. It's suitable

Comment: @VXp, 1. `auto` is default but the question is `how to keep that default`. 2. `margin auto and position fixed` matters because they change the default. 3. It's not clear at all. `Content's width` is too large for this concrete question.